# TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null with a correct script location and div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, firebase-realtime-database

so i try to figured out how i can fill up a < select> with brand name from my firebase table.
but when my page load innerHTML function found null

i have :

- a correct place for my script - happens when my script is put in a
  OnLoad section in my .js or right before the < /body>
- a correct name for my div - since it's the most common case, i rename it with 3 letter, never used anywhere else in the document

for now i have this :

```
<fieldset class="inline-fields" id="inline-field1">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group" id="select1">
            <select name="select-in" id="sel" class="form-control input-lg selectpicker" data-title="Marque" data-style="input-lg btn-default" data-live-search="true">
            <div id="selsel"></div>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form_after input-lg" id="form1" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form_after input-lg" id="form2" placeholder="Code Postal"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div></fieldset>
```

and i try to target the #selsel < div> in the #sel < select> but i paste the whole fieldset with bootstrap class for a more accurate information

here is the js :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var html = "";
            firebase.database().ref('brand').on('value', function(snapshot) {
                var brand = snapshot.val();
                for (var i in brand) {
                    if (brand.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof(i) !== 'function') {
                        elem = brand[i];
                        console.log(elem);
                        html += '<option>'
                        html += elem
                        html += '</option>'
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('selsel').innerHTML = html;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

like you can see, right before body ends, it use firebase to gather data, at the end, my elem output look like this
[elem output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODmpf.jpg)
and my html ouput like this 
[html output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXfxI.jpg)
another interesting thing is, when i put the #sel id in

```
document.getElementById('selsel').innerHTML = html;
```

instead of selsel (wich is respectively the select#sel and the sub-div#selsel) i dont see the error but nothing came populate the select

Comment: Are your DOM loaded already when you trying to set html? try to move your script tag to bottom of page, just before </body>

Comment: You can't have `div` inside `select`! Also since you use jQuery, why not `$('#sel').html(html)`?

Comment: @Maxx It already is. See the `</body>` right below the `</script>` in the code

Comment: @Andreas, i see, well then try Justionas comment

Comment: like you can see @Justinas when i remove my div inside the select and put the select id ( #sel) in my detElementByID function, it don't throw me and error but show nothing in select dropdown menu : http://imgur.com/a/tP9Tj

give the same result

Comment: @MehdiS. So maybe your `html` is empty?

Comment: what do you mean by empty ? when i try to use this script by targetting another random div in my html, it gives me a correct result :

[link(imggur)](http://imgur.com/mzEXdGG) 
EDIT : Wrong link

Comment: Try adding your code in `window.onload` function.

Comment: @sushmit.patil embed my script in a `$(window).load(function() {` change nothing, i get no error but also no result :
 [link(imggur)](http://i.imgur.com/DzhkLdt.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can't put `div` inside `select`, the browser won't render it. Running the snippet code you've provided and inspect element

[image]

Only allowed inside select `<option>` or `<optgroup>`.

So just append `<option>` elements directly inside `<select>`, there is no point of adding them inside `<div>`, unless you want custom view of options that's another thing. And in that case you can use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

Since you are using bootstrap why you don't use jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = "";
    firebase.database().ref('brand').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var brand = snapshot.val();
        for (var i in brand) {
            if (brand.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof(i) !== 'function') {
            elem = brand[i];
            console.log(elem);
            html += '<option>'
            html += elem
            html += '</option>'
            }
        }
        $("#sel").html(html);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**Edit 1**

Since you are using Bootstrap-select, first remove the class `selectpicker` from `<select>`

```
<div class="form-group" id="select1">
    <select name="select-in" id="sel" class="form-control input-lg" data-title="Marque" data-style="input-lg btn-default" data-live-search="true">
    </select>
</div>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html = "";
        firebase.database().ref('brand').on('value', function(snapshot) {
            var brand = snapshot.val();
            for (var i in brand) {
                if (brand.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof(i) !== 'function') {
                elem = brand[i];
                console.log(elem);
                html += '<option>'
                html += elem
                html += '</option>'
                }
            }
            $("#sel").html(html);
            $('#sel').selectpicker(); //you can pass options if you want

        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: oh maybe you are touching something because I use boostrap-select like you can see in the class of my select, is this can be a problem ?

Comment: anyway, i try your suggestion, remove the div, put jQuery like you did and still, nothing show, no error, but no brand to populate the select
 [link(imgur)](http://imgur.com/A1o5i8G)

Comment: yes for sure that's the problem, because bootstrap-select generates extra html based on the options inside select, which it was empty when it first loaded. so you need to load bootstrap-select after appending the options inside the select, I'll edit the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Awesome, That's my answer, thank you @Abanoub
[link (imgur)](http://imgur.com/CaH8kNX)